# IPython %run ignore print commands

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using several Jupyter Notebooks to split the tasks between different modules. In my main notebook I call another module `%run another_module.ipynb` which loads all my data. However, it also plots and prints everything I have in *another_module.ipynb*.

I want to keep the plots in *another_module.ipynb* to help me visualise the data but I don't want to reprint everything when calling `run another_module.ipynb`. Is there an option to prevent priniting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Override the `print` function and make it a no-op:

```py
_print_function = print  # create a backup in case you need it later
globals()["print"] = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```

2. Run the file with the `-i` flag. Without `-i`, the file is run in a new namespace, so your modifications to the global variables are lost; with `-i`, the file is run in the current namespace.

```py
%run -i another_module.ipynb
```

---

If you're using other methods to print logs (e.g., `sys.stdout.write()`, `logging`), it would be harder to create mocks for them. In that case, I would suggest redirecting the `stdout` or `stderr` pipe to `/dev/null`:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = fopen(os.devnull, "w")
%run -i another_module.ipynb
```

---

Both methods are considered hacks and should only be used when you know the consequences. The better thing to do here is to change your code in the notebook, either to add a `--verbose` flag to control logging, or use some logging library (e.g., `logging`) that supports turning off logging entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't manage to implement any of these solutions. In 1. do I override the code by placing it in the _main.ipynb_ notebook before calling `%run another_module.ipynb`? This didn't work. The `-i` flag in 2. does not change the way the results are printed out. Just to clarify I'm using `print` and `plt.plot` functions in _another_module.ipynb_ that I want to ignore in _main.ipynb_ notebook. I would be more than happy to control it from the notebook itself, but I am not sure how to incorporate `--verbose` flag.

Comment: @kmrydlx Sorry for the confusion, but what I meant was to first override `print` and then use `%run -i`. These two should be done together; they're not separate methods. A simple way to implement the verbose flag would be to use a global variable to indicate whether verbose mode is on, and replace all your `print` invocations with a custom logging function that checks the verbose global variable, and only print if verbose mode is on.

Comment: Awesome, yes this works for `print`. Is it possible to apply it to `plt.plot` as well?

Comment: Yes, you can import `matplotlib` in IPython and set its `plot()` method (and probably `show()` also) to the empty lambda function, and use `%run -i` to run the external script. It should work for other libraries as well.